# How do I publish with membership database included to a non Azure webhosting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I publish with membership database included to a non Azure webhosting?
That is the database that is automatically created when using new project in Visual studio.

I tried publishing a website witch worked but when trying to log in using the membership database the database seems to not have been included in the publishing process?

How do I include the database in the publish?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229862(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: What do you mean? Can I use that tool to publish the database. Or should i as the webhosting Company to run that tool on the server?

Comment: Quote: You can run Aspnet_regsql.exe without any command-line arguments to run a wizard that will walk you through specifying connection information for your SQL Server installation, and installing or removing the database elements for the membership, role management, profile, Web Parts personalization, and health monitoring features.